# Where is the file description field on the Android Drive app?

Tags: google-drive

I'm looking for the description field which is easily found when using Google Drive on the web (from a desktop). The field is shown here: http://gappstips.com/google-docs/add-a-description-to-your-google-docs/

When going to the Drive app (on Android 5.1) and going to the file information I just don't see it. I've been using the field extensively for my files and not being able to use it on the mobile version just renders the whole app useless for me.

Much appreciated.